# Plotly dash grid layout using dbc.Col & dbc.Row without the use of the bootstraps themes

Tags: layout, grid, themes, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

Is it possible to use the `dbc.Col` and `dbc.Row` functions to set up the grid layout *without* using the bootstrap themes ?

When adding for example the codepen.io css stylesheet, even when specifying the rows and columns, it displays everything stacked vertically.

The reason for not using the dbc themes is that I would like to personalise an external stylesheet and use that.
If there is no way around it, is it possible to override the dbc themes ? or modify them ?

```
import dash 
from dash import html
from dash import dcc
import dash_bootstrap_components

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css'])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.H5('row 1, col 1')),
        dbc.Col(html.H5('row 1, col 2'))
    ]),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col(html.H5('row 2, col 1')),
        dbc.Col(html.H5('row 2, col 2'))
    ])
], fluid=True)


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

it displays it as such :

```
row 1, col 1
row 1, col 2
row 2, col 1
row 2, col 2
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP` is just a link to a css stylesheet

```
>>> print(dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP)
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

So instead of passing `dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP` you could just pass

```
"https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap-grid.min.css"
```

to `external_stylesheets` to only get the grid system and flex utilities.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/contents/#css-files

---

You could also go to the non-minified version of the bootstrap grid styles

```
https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap-grid.css
```

and copy paste it in a css file in the `assets` folder which you can then modify as you wish. See the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources) for more info on that.